# CSS- Why does text moves after it is generated (animation)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, data-visualization

I have a quesiton about animation in CSS especially on typewriting effect.

I achieved type writing effect in animation.
However, 
even if I didn't set for the animation of transforming, 
once the type was generated, text moves to the righthand side.

Why did it happen and how do I fix this problem?
my css animation is as below.

```
    @keyframes fade{

        0%{
            transform:translateY(30px);
            opacity:0
        }

        100%{
            transform:translateY(0);
            opacity:1
        }

}
```

my full code is attached in the following link.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/abvVzev

Comment: Remove `text-align:center` from `.beggining` class.

Comment: @ismi Thank you so much!!! why did it happen?? It seems like textposition is animated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is inheriting text-align:center from its parent element .beggining.

.explanation is maintaining its center status as the width of the dive grows to 100%. That is why it looks like its position is animated.